# AWS Data Pipeline Pricing for On-demand Runs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

AWS Data pipeline documentation provides following information on pricing for data pipelines.

High frequency activities - $1.00 per month
Low frequency activities - $0.60 per month
Inactive pipelines -  $1.00 per month

> High Frequency activities are ones scheduled to execute more than once a day; for example, an activity scheduled to execute every hour or every 12 hours is High Frequency. Low Frequency activities are ones scheduled to execute one time a day or less.  Inactive pipelines are those in PENDING, INACTIVE, and FINISHED states.

I have run into the following problem. Suppose I configure an on-demand data pipeline with a single activity. I am repeatedly activating this on-demand pipeline with a different configuration ( ex - different query in each run ) - say 100 times per day.

Does this count as a single high frequency activity, despite being activated multiple times?

Is the cost for activating this pipeline 100 times per day still $1 per month ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Whether you are running the same activity multiple times or multiple activities one time/day, it is considered as high frequency.

Don't forget the instance costs that are associated with the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,
The AWS Data Pipeline pricing depends on two crterions:

1. Frequency of activity : High Frequency charged at $1.00 per month per activity 
   and low frequency charged at $0.60 per month per activity.
2. The number of activities in the pipeline.

Since in your scenario you are running a single activity 100 times a day (High Frequency activity), it would cost $1.00 per month.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the data pipeline pricing is for single activity and its based on frequency at which its used, which you have quoted very well. Based on the number of execution, your frequency slab changes and so does the price.

However there is some limit to activate the existing pipeline multiple times.

Yes, the cost will be 1$/month for multiple execution of single activity since the datapipeline already in high frequency, however there will be separate price involved for other resources used in the activity.